# Continuous maps in from Banach space to $\ell ^\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Prove that a linear map $M\colon X\mapsto \ell^p, \; p\geqslant 1$ is continuous iff for every sequence $(x_k)$ that converges in $X$ to $x \in X$, we have that the $n$-th term of the sequence $Mx_k$ converges to the $n$-th term of $Mx$ for all $n$.

My try:
$(\Rightarrow)$ If $M$ is continuous $\|Mx_n - Mx\| \leq \epsilon$ hence $|(Mx_n)_i - (Mx)_i| \leq \epsilon$

$(\Leftarrow)$
$$y\in \ell^p \Rightarrow \|y\|_p < \infty \Rightarrow  \exists N : \|y\|_p^p = \sum_{i = 1}^N |y_i|^p + \underbrace{\sum_{i = N+1}^\infty |y_i|^p}_{\leq \epsilon}$$

So we can find an $N$ such that
$$\|Mx-y\|_p^p =  \underbrace{\sum_{i = 1}^N |(Mx)_i - y_i|^p}_{\leq N\epsilon} + \underbrace{\sum_{i = N+1}^\infty |(Mx)_i - y_i|^p}_{\leq 2\epsilon} \leq (N+2)\epsilon.$$
Hence by closed graph we are done.
Is this correct? What happens when $p = \infty$ ?

Comment: In the $(\Leftarrow)$ implication, where do you use the hypothesis that $x_k\to x$ in $X$?

Comment: The problem is that $N$ depends on $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closed graph theorem is indeed the idea. Let $\{x_k\}$ a sequence of elements of $X$ which converges to $0$ and such that $Mx_k\to y\in\ell^p$. As the $n$-th terms of $Mx_k$ converges to the $n$-th one of the null sequence, we have $(Mx_k)^{(n)}\to 0$. As for $1\leqslant p\leqslant+\infty$, we have for all $k$ and for all $n$,
$$|y^{(n)}|\leqslant |y^{(n)}-(Mx_k)^{(n)}|+|(Mx_k)^{(n)}|\leqslant \lVert y-Mx_k\rVert_{\ell^p}+|(Mx_k)^{(n)}|$$
so $y=0$.

Comment: Thanks, So we can always change convergent sequences $x_k \rightarrow x$ to some that converges to 0 i suppose.
Can you please tell me what I did wrong?